# How to fetch json array in android

Tags: android

fetch json data and set Model class this data was set list view or recyclerview details fetch json data and set Model class this data was set list view or recyclerview details fetch json data and set Model class this data was set list view or recyclerview details

```
private void getdata() {
        String url = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
        final StringRequest placeReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String Response) {
                Log.e("Place Response", Response.toString());
                pDialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(Response);
                    JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("history");
                    Log.e("jArray", "" + jArray);
                    ArrayList<ModelClass> modelClassArrayList = new ArrayList<ModelClass>();
                    ModelClass modelClass = new ModelClass();
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String oneObjectsItem = oneObject.getString("type");
                            if (oneObjectsItem.equals("approval")) {
                                modelClass.setTransactionid(oneObject.getString("transactionid"));
                                modelClass.setName(oneObject.getString("name"));
                                modelClass.setAddress(oneObject.getString("address"));
                                modelClass.setType(oneObject.getString("type"));
                                modelClass.setTag(oneObject.getString("tag"));
                                modelClass.setStatus(oneObject.getString("status"));
                                modelClass.setDate(oneObject.getString("date"));
                                modelClass.setImage(oneObject.getString("image"));
                                modelClassArrayList.add(modelClass);
                                Log.e("name", "" + oneObject.getString("name"));
                                Log.e("address", "" + oneObject.getString("address"));
                                Log.e("type", "" + oneObject.getString("type"));
                                Log.e("status", "" + oneObject.getString("status"));
                                Log.e("date", "" + oneObject.getString("date"));
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("error", "" + e);
                        }
                    }
                    for (int j = 0; j < modelClassArrayList.size(); j++) {
                        Log.e("name", "" + modelClassArrayList.get(j).getDate());
                    }
                    Log.e("Size ", "" + modelClassArrayList.size());
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    Log.e("Error", "" + e1);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Place", "Error Response: " + error.getMessage());
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("userid", "1");
                Log.e("Restaurant", "Posting params: " + params.toString());
                return params;
            }
        };
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(placeReq);
    }
```

private class Connection extends AsyncTask
    {
        static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
        static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
        static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
        static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
        static final String KEY_DESC = "description";

```
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Log.e("xml", "" + xml);
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
        Log.e("doc", "" + doc.toString());
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
        Log.e("nl", "" + nl.toString());
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            ModelClass modelClass = new ModelClass();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            modelClass.setId(parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            modelClass.setName(parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            modelClass.setCost("Rs." + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
            modelClass.setDescription(parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
            modelClass.setDate(parser.getValue(e, "date"));
            modelClassArrayList.add(modelClass);
            Log.e("Size", "" + modelClassArrayList.size() + "" + i);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < modelClassArrayList.size(); j++) {
            Log.e("Id", modelClassArrayList.get(j).getId());
            Log.e("Name", modelClassArrayList.get(j).getName());
            Log.e("Cost", modelClassArrayList.get(j).getCost());
            Log.e("Desc", modelClassArrayList.get(j).getDescription());
            Log.e("date", modelClassArrayList.get(j).getDate());
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
    }
}
```

`class XMLParser{
    public XMLParser(){
    }
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return xml;
    }
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return doc;
    }
    public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
        Node child;
        if( elem != null){
            if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                    if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                        return child.getNodeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
    public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
}`
`public class FavouriteAnimalListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
Context context;
ArrayList<FavouritreAnimal> favouriteAnimalArray;


FavouritreAnimal animalfavourite;

public FavouriteAnimalListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FavouritreAnimal> favouriteAnimalArray) {
    this.context = context;
    this.favouriteAnimalArray = favouriteAnimalArray;
}

@Override
public favouriteListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_card_vew_favourite_list_view, parent, false);
    favouriteListViewHolder favouriteListViewHolder = new favouriteListViewHolder(v);

    return favouriteListViewHolder;
}




@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(favouriteListViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    animalfavourite = favouriteAnimalArray.get(position);

    holder.tvFavouriteAnimalName.setText(animalfavourite.getAnimalname());

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(animalfavourite.getAnimalimage())
            .into(holder.ivFavouriteAnimalImage);


    String animaldesc = Html.fromHtml(context.getString(animalfavourite.getAnimal_description())).toString();
    if (animaldesc.length() > 100) {
        String animaldesc1 = Html.fromHtml(animaldesc).toString();
        animaldesc = animaldesc1.substring(0, 110) + "\n" + "...";
    }


    holder.tvFavouriteAnimalDescription.setText(animaldesc);
    holder.cvFavouriteanimal.setTag(R.string.app_name, animalfavourite.getAnimalid());
    holder.cvFavouriteanimal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            CardView cv = (CardView) v;
            int id = (int) cv.getTag(R.string.app_name);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, FavourityAnimalViewPager.class);
            intent.putExtra(Utils.ANIMAL_ID, position);
            context.startActivity(intent);

            ((Activity)context).finish();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return favouriteAnimalArray.size();
}

static class favouriteListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cvFavouriteanimal;
    TextView tvFavouriteAnimalName, tvFavouriteAnimalDescription;
    ImageView ivFavouriteAnimalImage;

    public favouriteListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cvFavouriteanimal = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_favourite_animal);
        tvFavouriteAnimalName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_favourite_animal_name);
        ivFavouriteAnimalImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ib_favourite_animal_image);
        tvFavouriteAnimalDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_favourite_animal_description);
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: Can you provide more detail of your question.

Comment: Indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

```
ProgressDialog pDialog;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
EditText search;
ArrayList<ModelClass> modelClassArrayList;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

    getDataToServer();
    addFnction();
}

void addFnction() {
    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            charSequence = charSequence.toString();

            ArrayList<ModelClass> filteredList = new ArrayList<ModelClass>();

            for (int j = 0; j < modelClassArrayList.size(); j++) {

                final String text = modelClassArrayList.get(j).getName().toLowerCase();
                if (text.contains(charSequence)) {

                    filteredList.add(modelClassArrayList.get(j));
                }
            }

            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
            AdapterClass adapterClass = new AdapterClass(MainActivity.this, filteredList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterClass);
            adapterClass.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
}

private void getDataToServer() {
    String url = "http://theappguruz.in/php/DemoJSON/api/user/contacts#sthash.LouFoc7n.dpuf";
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();
    final StringRequest placeReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String Response) {
            Log.e("Place Response", Response.toString());
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(Response);
                JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("Payload");

                String msg = json.getString("Message");

                Log.e("Masssssss", "" + msg);

                Log.e("jArray", "" + jArray);
                modelClassArrayList = new ArrayList<ModelClass>();

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    ModelClass modelClass = new ModelClass();
                    JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    modelClass.setName(oneObject.getString("FirstName"));
                    modelClass.setState(oneObject.getString("LastName"));
                    JSONObject twoObject = oneObject.getJSONObject("Phone");
                    modelClass.setDescription(twoObject.getString("Mobile"));
                    modelClassArrayList.add(modelClass);
                }

                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

                Collections.sort(modelClassArrayList, new Comparator<ModelClass>() {
                    public int compare(ModelClass p1, ModelClass p2) {
                        return (p1.getName()).compareTo(p2.getName());
                    }
                });

                AdapterClass adapterClass = new AdapterClass(MainActivity.this, modelClassArrayList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterClass);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exxx", "" + e);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Place", "Error Response: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return params;
        }
    };
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(placeReq);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

public class AdapterClass extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList modelClassArrayList;
    ModelClass modelClass;

```
public AdapterClass(Context context, ArrayList<ModelClass> modelClassArrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.modelClassArrayList = modelClassArrayList;
}

@Override
public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_card_vew_list_view, parent, false);
    ListViewHolder listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder(v);
    return listViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ListViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    modelClass = modelClassArrayList.get(position);
    holder.textViewcity.setText(modelClass.getName());
    holder.textViewstate.setText(modelClass.getState());
    holder.textViewdscri.setText(modelClass.getDescription());

    holder.cvView.setTag(position);


    holder.cvView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("Position", "" + position);
            Log.e("Name", "" + modelClassArrayList.get(position).getName());
            Log.e("State", "" + modelClassArrayList.get(position).getState());
            Log.e("Description", "" + modelClassArrayList.get(position).getDescription());

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondAct.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", modelClassArrayList.get(position).getName());
            intent.putExtra("last", modelClassArrayList.get(position).getState());
            intent.putExtra("phone", modelClassArrayList.get(position).getDescription());
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return modelClassArrayList.size();
}

static class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cvView;
    TextView textViewdscri, textViewstate, textViewcity;


    public ListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cvView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        textViewcity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.city);
        textViewstate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.state);
        textViewdscri = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dscri);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do not post the code in the answer section if it just the continuation.

Answer (score 0):

public class static_data extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ArrayList<ModelPrice> modelPriceArrayList = new ArrayList<ModelPrice>();
RecyclerView rv;
AdapterPrice adapterClass;
LinearLayoutManager llm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_static_data);
    rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
    fill_data();

    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    llm = new LinearLayoutManager(static_data.this);
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
    adapterClass = new AdapterPrice(static_data.this, modelPriceArrayList);
    rv.setAdapter(adapterClass);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.setting_data, menu);
    return true;

}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.a:
            Collections.sort(modelPriceArrayList, new Comparator<ModelPrice>() {
                public int compare(ModelPrice p1, ModelPrice p2) {
                    return (p1.getName()).compareTo(p2.getName());
                }
            });
            rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
            llm = new LinearLayoutManager(static_data.this);
            rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
            adapterClass = new AdapterPrice(static_data.this, modelPriceArrayList);
            rv.setAdapter(adapterClass);

            return true;
        case R.id.z:
            Collections.sort(modelPriceArrayList, new Comparator<ModelPrice>() {
                public int compare(ModelPrice p1, ModelPrice p2) {
                    return p2.getName().compareTo(p1.getName());
                }
            });
            rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
            llm = new LinearLayoutManager(static_data.this);
            rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
            adapterClass = new AdapterPrice(static_data.this, modelPriceArrayList);
            rv.setAdapter(adapterClass);
            return true;

        case R.id.l:
            Collections.sort(modelPriceArrayList, new Comparator<ModelPrice>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(ModelPrice p1, ModelPrice p2) {
                    return (int) p1.getPrice() - p2.getPrice();
                }
            });

            rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
            llm = new LinearLayoutManager(static_data.this);
            rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
            adapterClass = new AdapterPrice(static_data.this, modelPriceArrayList);
            rv.setAdapter(adapterClass);
            return true;

        case R.id.h:
            Collections.sort(modelPriceArrayList, new Comparator<ModelPrice>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(ModelPrice p1, ModelPrice p2) {
                    return (int) p2.getPrice() - p1.getPrice();
                }
            });
            rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
            llm = new LinearLayoutManager(static_data.this);
            rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
            adapterClass = new AdapterPrice(static_data.this, modelPriceArrayList);
            rv.setAdapter(adapterClass);
            return true;


        case R.id.New:


            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(static_data.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Blah Blah...");

            final EditText textViewcolor = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.color_name1);
            final EditText textViewprice = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.color_price1);
            Button btnok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
            Button btncancle = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btncancle);

            btnok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String name = String.valueOf(textViewcolor.getText());
                    String price = String.valueOf(textViewprice.getText());
                    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice(name, Integer.parseInt(price)));
                    adapterClass.notifyItemChanged(0);
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

            btncancle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


            dialog.show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
void fill_data() {
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("Red", 25));
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("white", 215));
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("Yello", 245));
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("Balck", 245));
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("DarkViolet", 275));
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("DeepPink", 225));
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("Fuchsia", 235));
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("Gold", 425));
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("Gray", 25));
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("HotPink", 725));
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("IndianRed", 525));
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("Indigo", 225));
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("Gainsboro", 3325));
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("Brown", 425));
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("Chartreuse", 725));
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("DarkCyan", 5));
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("DarkGrey", 225));
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("DarkSlateBlue", 285));
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("MintCream", 275));
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("PaleVioletRed", 825));
    modelPriceArrayList.add(new ModelPrice("PaleVioletRed", 625));

}
```

}